# MVC4 link automatically redirected to default INDEX page/action even if defined action name with controller

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

i am creating web mobile application in mvc4.
My problem is when I click on particular link in my application,it works well,
but sometimes it automatically redirected to `INDEX` page that is set as default page in `global.asax` as

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional         } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Now I don't know why its automatically redirected to INDEX page,even if I have already defined controller and action name where it show redirected as,

```
<a href='@(Url.Action( "ActivityWall", "Home"))' > </a>
```

logically it should redirect to "`ActivityWall`" page,which it does.but sometime only it goes to INDEX page.then when I clear my cookie problem will again solved but after some time it again start redirecting to INDEX page.

I also posted question related to cookies issue yesterday,but I think that is nit main issue.

can someone help please ?

Comment: why are you writing @(Url.Action( "ActivityWall", "Home")) you can write @Url.Action( "ActivityWall", "Home") do you have any mobile or jquery libraries running on your page? try running your code without any fancy css or js.

Comment: yes @Peter,actually my original link is 
 <a href='@(Url.Action( "ActivityWall", "Home"))' class = "link-header" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'activitywall', 'click', 'activitywall']);">
                        <img alt="" class="menu-icon" src="../../Content/Images/icon/home.png" title="Home" />
                        <span class="menu-name">Home</span>
                        <hr class="menu-divider" />
                    </a>                                                      which is necessary,and its working fine also. but sometiome only something goes wried and problem occurs.

Comment: Please check this issue http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/280 maybe you have the same caching problem.

Comment: thanks peter,let me check the link

Comment: its not working @Peter, i try to set cache null bu its not working. and here i have no separate views for mobile and desktop.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to catch this in action with Fiddler or firebug, etc and watch if a redirect really comes from the app or if something else happens. Your link above should stay going to /Home/ActivityWall, but without seeing your code inside ActivityWall we can't say for sure whats going on there.

Watch the location every tine you click on that link. If a redirect comes back either you have an action filter doing a redirect or your code does it for some reason you aren't aware, or its a security misconfiguration.

Comment: i tried every possible debugging but unable to find solution thats why i have posted it here.